# Kivy: How To Display 'Correct!' When Input Is Correct?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm trying to create a system that will show 'correct' when the input is correct. But I'm so confused about how classes and functions work even after watching tutorials and reading through documentations, as I'm new to Python and Kivy.

This is my kv code so far

```
<CorrectLayout>
    id: correctlayout
    Label:
        text: 'Gesture Correct!'
        background_normal:'bgpics/translateback.jpg'
        pos_hint:{"x":-0.15,"y":-.43}
        color: 1,1,0,1,1
        font_size: '45sp'
        font_name: 'EraserRegular.ttf'
    Image:
        source: 'bgpics/check2.png'
        pos_hint:{"x":0.64,"y":.03}
        size_hint: .1, .1
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
<LetterAScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'bgpics/bluebg.jpg'
    CorrectLayout:

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Learning the FSL Alphabet'
            background_normal:'bgpics/chalk2.png'
            pos_hint:{"x":0.009,"y":.43}
            font_size: '45sp'
            font_name: 'SqueakyChalkSound.ttf'

        Image:
            source: 'handgesture/a.png'
            pos_hint:{"x":0.009,"y":.15}
            size_hint: .40, .70
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Image:
            source: 'handgesture/a.png'
            pos_hint:{"x":0.43,"y":.15}
            size_hint: .40, .70
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Button:
            text: "NEXT"
            background_normal:'bgpics/translateback.jpg'
            font_size: '35sp'
            font_name: 'vtks.ttf'
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint:{"x":.87,"y":.6}
            size_hint: .1, .1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'letterb'
        Button:
            text: "QUIT"
            background_normal:'bgpics/translateback.jpg'
            font_size: '35sp'
            font_name: 'vtks.ttf'
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint:{"x":.87,"y":.2}
            size_hint: .1, .1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'

<LetterBScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'bgpics/bluebg.jpg'
    CorrectLayout:

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Learning the FSL Alphabet'
            background_normal:'bgpics/chalk2.png'
            pos_hint:{"x":0.009,"y":.43}
            font_size: '45sp'
            font_name: 'SqueakyChalkSound.ttf'
        Image:
            source: 'handgesture/b.png'
            pos_hint:{"x":0.009,"y":.15}
            size_hint: .40, .70
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Image:
            source: 'handgesture/b.png'
            pos_hint:{"x":0.43,"y":.15}
            size_hint: .40, .70
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Button:
            text: "NEXT"
            background_normal:'bgpics/translateback.jpg'
            font_size: '35sp'
            font_name: 'vtks.ttf'
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint:{"x":.87,"y":.6}
            size_hint: .1, .1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'lettera'
        Button:
            text: "BACK"
            background_normal:'bgpics/translateback.jpg'
            font_size: '35sp'
            font_name: 'vtks.ttf'
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint:{"x":.87,"y":.4}
            size_hint: .1, .1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'lettera'
        Button:
            text: "QUIT"
            background_normal:'bgpics/translateback.jpg'
            font_size: '35sp'
            font_name: 'vtks.ttf'
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint:{"x":.87,"y":.2}
            size_hint: .1, .1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
```

and my .py file (did not include the unnecessary parts)

```
class CorrectLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

class LetterAScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LetterBScreen(Screen):
    pass
sm = ScreenManager(transition=SwapTransition())
sm.add_widget(LetterAScreen(name='lettera'))
sm.add_widget(LetterBScreen(name='letterb'))
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

I just formatted everything in first so that I know where they would be placed, but I don't know where to take it from here. My .py file just used 'pass' to all the classes I included in the kv file. I don't know how to implement classes and functions to achieve what I need.

The input will come from a keyboard input, and will decide from a dictionary if the letter matches with the picture.  If the letter is a match with the picture, then the picture should appear beside it, along with the `CorrectLayout`. Then when the user clicks next in the `LetterAscreen` and proceeds to the `LetterBScreen`, then clicks previous, I need the `LetterAScreen` to revert to not having the `CorrectLayout` and the second image.

Will anyone help me? Please?

Comment: please help me I really need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use a `TextInput` widget to get some user input. Then you need to define a function that will check what the user put in to the name (the `source`) of your `Image` widget. Call that function with some button to check the user input. Here is a very short example of how to do that (make sure the files are named *main.py* and *main.kv*)

`main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App

class MainApp(App):
    def check_answer(self, text_to_check, *args):
        # You can ignore what is held in *args, but keep it there
        # Get the name of the image
        the_image = self.root.ids['the_image']
        the_image_name = the_image.source

        # Get the user's input
        print("the image name was: ", the_image_name)
        print("Your guess was: ", text_to_check)
        if the_image_name == text_to_check:
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Incorrect :(")

MainApp().run()
```

`main.kv`

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    Image:
        id: the_image
        source: "a.png"
    TextInput:
        id: the_text_input
        hint_text: "Type your answer here"
    Button:
        text: "Check Answer"
        on_release:
            # Call the function we defined in the python file
            # Pass the text that the user put in by referencing the id of the
            # TextInput and getting the value of the text
            app.check_answer(the_text_input.text)
```

Comment: Thank you again for helping me again Sir! Big help, so much. I have a little follow up question. If I have 26 different Image png for the 26 alphabets, do I have to call them using different id's?

Comment: If I were you, I would change the `source:` attribute (the file that is displayed) of the `Image` widget when you want to show another image. That way the `id` hasn't changed, it's still `the_image`, but when you check `the_image.source` it will be the name of the new image

Comment: So your "NEXT" button would no longer change screens, it would just set `the_image.source = "b.png"`. That's the simplest thing to do. A more general way would be to set the `source` to something that isn't hard coded. Maybe you would set it to "random_alphabet_letter.png", or get the next letter in the alphabet like the `next_letter` function I wrote in that earlier question of yours