# How To End A Loop When A Condition is Satisfied?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, loops

As per my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584699/kivy-how-to-display-correct-when-input-is-correct/55600887#55600887), my question today is related to it. I have a constantly updating global variable, and I pass that variable to a function. That function consists of a loop and conditional statements. I want the loop to end when the condition is satisfied, but it keeps on looping.

Here is my code.

```
class LetterAScreen:
    def identity(self): 
        global where
        lol=Identifier()
        lol.fn_compare()
        print where

    def verifier(self):
        global where
        verify=where
        if verify != 1:
            while (count>0):
                print ("try again")
                run=LetterAScreen()
                run.identity()
                run.verifier
                print ("try again")
                count += 1
        else:
            print ("correct")
```

The "Correct" is when the variable turns to one. Otherwise, it is not correct and the user should try again. The output ends up looking like this.

```
#incorrect inputs
19
try again
try again
19
try again
try again
19
try again
try again
19
try again
try again
19
try again
try again
#correct inputs but loop doesn't end
1
try again
try again
1
try again
try again
1
try again
try again
1
try again
try again
```

The essential part about Identifier class is only the updating variable. I believe the problem is with the class I've shared. I'm really unfamiliar how this works. I hope you could help me.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the detail of your code, but you can break out of a loop using the `break` keyword. For example you can do `if ...: break`, replacing `...` with the condition that will allow to exit the loop.

Comment: If you keep adding to `count` it will never break out.

Comment: how do I break out of the loop only when the `if condition` is True? I tried adding break at the end but it ended up ending the loop even when the input is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things to note here:

- Why are your creating a new `LetterAScreen` object in your loop?
- Be carefull when using a global variable, usually there are other ways to solve this cleaner.

I don't know what the `Identifier` class does but guess the `fn_compare` function of that class will change the `where` variable? Also, creating a new `Identifier` on every call of the `identity` function seems something you should change.

That being said, the `verifier` method needs to be adjusted as followed:

```
def verifier(self):
    global where
    count = 1
    while (count>0 and where != 1):
        print ("try again")
        self.identity()
        count += 1
    print ("correct")
```

You shouldn't assign the global `where` variable to a local one, this will cause problems because the local one will not be updated in the loop. You can compare to this global `where` variable directly. Also I removed the `run` variable, you are executing in an instance of the `LetterAScreen` class so you can call the `identity` method on the self object (similar to a `this` in JS).

Comment: How do I end the loop when the input is already correct? I included your remarks in my code but it seemed I just refactored my syntax. Thank you.

Comment: By the input is correct, I assume you mean verify = 1? So it will not go in the loop.

Comment: the input comes from the global where variable which updates every 1 second. I added an if condition so that if the input is not 1, it will have to loop over and over until the input is 1, by then it could break the loop. I'm sorry I'm new to Python.

Comment: I read your question again and adjusted my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

first of all you probably don't need to create new instance inside a method "verifier" (methods are already called when the instance is created, you can access the instance using "self" variable. 
So instead of

```
run=LetterAScreen()
run.identity()
```

write

```
self.identity()
```

also instead of of using complex "global" approach
you can create instance variable like self.verify and change it inside "identify"

```
class LetterAScreen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.verify = 0
```

also infinitive loop usually created like this

```
while True:
```

Always be careful using "global" is tricky and in most of cases you can do anything in simples and readable way, so I would recommend you remove all globals from this script, you can return params from functions, use mutable objects etc.

Comment: How do I end the loop when the input is already correct? I included your remarks in my code but it seemed I just refactored my syntax.

Comment: if self.verify: break